# Removing a module from the blacklist

Tags: fedora, kernel-modules

How do I remove a module from the blacklist? I need b43 to load on start but `journalctl` tells me that it is not loading because its in the blacklist.

How do I remove it from the blacklist? I'm using Fedora 20.

Comment: Look for a blacklist file in `/etc/modprobe.d/`...

Answer (score 3):

I found the files that where blacklisting my module here: `/lib/modprobe.d/`

Answer (score 1):

> `/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf`

search in this file for a module name and if it's indeed in there then comment out or delete the string.

Comment: The module could also be blacklisted in a named file under `/etc/modprobe.d/$module.conf`...

Comment: I did not find any files in there. Is there not something I can use with ```modprobe``` to remove the module from the blacklist?

Comment: @Dominique you should be still able to load module with `sudo modeprobe modulename`